# Is there a way to make a div inside a absolutely positioned div scroll on overflow?

Tags: css

I am trying to fix an issue where the contents of a modal are overflowing by setting a percentage maximum height and `overflow: scroll;` for the contents of the modal.

The modal is absolutely positioned, somewhat responsive and in the inspector I can see that it's height is being set correctly. My problem is that I am unable to set a percentage based height for the contents of the modal.

Pretty accurate replication of the problem I am trying to solve:

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="second">
    <div class="header"><h2>Header</h2></div>
    <div class="content">
      <ul>
        <li>Asdf</li><li>Asdf</li><li>Asdf</li><li>Asdf</li>
        <li>Asdf</li><li>Asdf</li><li>Asdf</li><li>Asdf</li>
        <li>Asdf</li><li>Asdf</li><li>Asdf</li><li>Asdf</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.first {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.second {
  position: absolute;
  left: 80px;
  right: 80px;
  top: 8%;
  bottom: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  max-height: 80%;

  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: red;
}

.content {
  width: 50%;
  height: 1%;
  overflow: scroll;

  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: green;
}

li {
  width: 2000px;
  height: 100px;

  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

I would expect for the `content div` to get it's height set based on a percentage of it's parent (`second div`) and not overflow but it's height seems to be completely unrestricted.

What would be the best way to fix this while still maintaining the responsive nature of `second div`? And why does setting the height of `content div` not work in this case?

Comment: Codepen link with the above code example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qzvLyV?editors=1100#0

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `height` to the parent element (`.second`), for `.content` to calculate its own `height` from. Remember, `height` values cascade down. If you want an element to have a relative `height`, you need a fixed `height` at some point in its hierarchy, with *each* element in between the target element and the element with the fixed `height` having a relative `height` as well.

In this case, simply setting a `height` of `100%` on `.second` will give you the desired result:

```css
.first {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.second {
  position: absolute;
  left: 80px;
  right: 80px;
  top: 8%;
  bottom: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  max-height: 80%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  width: 50%;
  height: 20%;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: green;
}

li {
  width: 2000px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="second">
    <div class="header">
      <h2>Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <ul>
        <li>Asdf</li>
        <li>Asdf</li>
        <li>Asdf</li>
        <li>Asdf</li>
        <li>Asdf</li>
        <li>Asdf</li>
        <li>Asdf</li>
        <li>Asdf</li>
        <li>Asdf</li>
        <li>Asdf</li>
        <li>Asdf</li>
        <li>Asdf</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does make it so that you can set a percentage height to the contents, however when you explicitly set the height for the `second div` it stops being responsive and furthermore the contents will still overflow the modal if their height is set 100%. The height of the contents doesn't seem to be based on the actual height of the modal but instead it always goes all the way to the bottom of the page.